# GA send event, not working with custom dimensions

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to include list of custom dimensions when sending GA click event.

This code works:

```
ga('send', 'event', category, action, label, {
  'hitCallback': function () {
    //some code goes here
  }
});
```

But when adding custom dimensions:

```
ga('send', 'event', category, action, label, customDimensions.dimensionsToSend, {
   hitCallback': function () {
      //some code
   },
   'hitCallbackFail': function () {
      alert("Unable to send Google Analytics data");
   }
});
```

Neither hitCallback nor hitCallbackFail gets fired.
I read in a few places ([like here](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Code/How-do-I-add-Custom-Dimensions-to-GA-Event/td-p/478305#)) that I should be able to add custom dimensions to GA send event function, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your second code block is that the custom dimensions are not being set appropriately. You can't pass the custom dimensions in as a further argument to the main `ga()` function. Instead, you need to pass them in through the `fieldsObject` (as part of the object you're sending as the last argument), like this:

```
ga('send', 'event', category, action, label, {
   'dimension1': 'Some value', // Custom Dimension 1
   'dimension2': 'Some value 2', // Custom Dimension 2
   'hitCallback': function () {
      //some code
   }
});
```

This is shorthand for:

```
ga('send', {
   'hitType': 'event', 
   'eventCategory': category, 
   'eventAction': action, 
   'eventLabel': label,
   'dimension1': 'Some value', // Custom Dimension 1
   'dimension2': 'Some value 2', // Custom Dimension 2
   'hitCallback': function () {
      //some code
   }
});
```

See the [`ga()` command queue reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference).

Note also that `hitCallbackFail` is not a valid field; that won't get called on a failure.

See the [list of available fields](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference).

In fact, the function you provide to `hitCallback` will get executed whether the hit you sent was successful or if Google Analytics rejected the hit. The only times it won't get executed are if the Google Analytics library does not load, or if the server connection fails.

If you have code you want to execute even if the server fails, you can use a timeout. See this example from the above page:

```
// Use a timeout to ensure the execution of critical application code.
ga('send', 'pageview', {'hitCallback': criticalCode});
setTimeout(criticalCode, 2000);

// Only run the critical code once.
var alreadyCalled = false;
function criticalCode() {
  if (alreadyCalled) return;
  alreadyCalled = true;

  // Run critical code here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Colin.Your answer was helpful. I found the actual reason and solution to this issue.
Because customDimensions.dimensionsToSend is an object, the next object which includes hitCallback function is not taken into account at all.
To fix this I needed to add hitCallback function inside customDimensions.dimensionsToSend object. Now it's working.
Thanks

Comment: So long as `customDimensions.dimensionsToSend` contains the right keys (e.g., `dimension1`), what this means is that you've made `customDimensions.dimensionsToSend` the `fieldsObject` passed in the call. Which will work, but you may want to clean up your naming convention for that object.